# php function file_exists with condeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-io, user-profile

I am using codeigniter, I want to show a user page with his profile picture shown. When a user uploads a profile picture, it will get the same name as the username (where the old profile picture will be overwritten). If he hasn't uploaded a profile picture, then a questionmark picture is shown. I use file_exists function, but it returns every time false.

```
$filename = base_url().'images/userimg/'.$this->session->userdata('username');

if(file_exists($filename)){
echo '<img src="'.$filename.'" width="300" height="300"  /><br/>';
}
else { 
echo '<img src="'.base_url().'images/no_image.jpg" width="300" height="300"  /><br/>';  
}
```

Comment: probaply because `$filename` doesn't have an extension such as `.jpg`

Comment: and you can use FCPATH instead of base_url to check the real path of the image not url path..

Comment: you should post the code which stores the picture too

Comment: echo `$filename` and see what is the path being printed.

Comment: It works without extension and the path of $filename is correct, if I remove the if and else statement, the right profile picture is shown. That is why I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: concatenate the image extension with image name then try again

Comment: Fixed it. I had to use FCPATH with file extension, only then file_exists function works. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 2):

Change your codes into this:

```
$filename = './images/userimg/'.$this->session->userdata('username');
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your problem results from thae usage or url instead of local server path. That base_url in the config file contains an URL and the file_exists function should work with a full local path - for which you can use FCPATH (like Svetlio suggested) or any other way. Although the file_exists should work with URL , i think there will be more trouble with it than a full path.